# Shooting Star Anomaly

Tags: stars

Tonight I was walking home from the supermarket and saw an unusual shooting star.

It appeared at a point in the sky, bright red and accelerated to a visible extent far faster than any other shooting star I have seen, in an **apparent** downward trajectory. Living in Australia my entire life I have seen many shooting stars but none of them has red color either. And it did not seem to diminish brightness, and disappeared from sight at a singular point.

My guess at this point is a firework that was fired from an aircraft or drone, strapped to some sort of fire retardant apparatus to quell the energy upon release.

Does anyone else have better ideas?

Comment: It still can be a [meteoroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid#Colours) because they come in bunch of color effects. **Red** meteoroid color happens when super-heated air plasma which they produces are composed mainly of nitrogen and oxygen.

Comment: Sure I guessed something along the lines would be the case, but the acceleration and constancy of the brightness combined with the striking red colour is really what had me a little disturbed, I mean I don't know what shooting stars look like elsewhere because I've never travelled, but here I have only ever seen ones in the ball park of star light